# HoloLens 2 / Unity / MRTK : Boundary System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I've been trying to get the Boundary System working in Unity but without much luck. There seems to be little in documentation apart from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/boundary/boundary-system-getting-started?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) and the MRTK sample which doesnt seem to do anything.

My end goal is to show a "safe area" in which the user can operate.

To Replicate:

1. Create a new project and set it up in Unity follwing this guide : [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/)
2. Import the "Mixed Reality Toolkit Examples" Boundary Demo
3. Open The Demo scene and make sure the profiles are assigned
4. Deploy the Demo to the HoloLens 2 and the only thing shown is the text telling me about the boundry visualization

Things I've Tried:

- Creating a new project
- Installing MRTK Scene Understanding and Plane Finding

Versions:
Unity 2020.3.29f1
MRTK 2.8.2

Has anyone got this working, or is there a more helpful guide?

[image: Boundary Settings]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Boundary system overview — MRTK2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/boundary/boundary-system-getting-started) said, the Boundary system is designed for VR headset.

> The Boundary system provides support for visualizing **Virtual Reality** boundary components in mixed reality applications. Boundaries define the area in which users can safely move around while wearing a **VR headset**. Boundaries are an important component of a mixed reality experience to help users avoid unseen obstacles while wearing a **VR headset**.

HoloLens does not support the concept of boundaries. To achieve what you want, you may take advantage of [Spatial awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/spatial-awareness/spatial-awareness-getting-started).

Comment: Hello JayZuo-MSFT

Thank you for explaining that,

I see that in the documention does indeed say a VR headset, despit it existing in the **MixedRealityToolkit**

It is a shame that this feature doesnt work with the HoloLens 2. I thought that something such as "Stay inside this safe zone" would be quite important for a device that is getting a user to perform physcial actions.

I will impliment something myself.

Thanks,
tfcmad

Comment: Windows Mixed Reality includes both Holographic devices and Immersive VR devices. HoloLens does not have the concept of boundaries as it has a see-through display. Unlike VR devices' opaque display that blocks out the physical environment while wearing the headset. Holographic devices allow the user to see the physical environment. Thus, VR devices have the concept of boundaries that need to be configured like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/enthusiast-guide/set-up-windows-mixed-reality#set-up-your-room-boundary. The Boundary system in MRTK just utilizes it.

Comment: Having a library named MixedReality which works with Virtual Reality seems counter intuitive to me. Thanks for explaining how the Boundary system works in VR, it makes sense that when you can’t see your environment you’d need a system like that. However, I’d say there is a case for a similar system on the HoloLens given it can be used in an industrial environment.